# Importing modules and HTTP request in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm playing around a little with Elm but I'm not sure how to solve this properly. The purpose is to call and external API everytime that an item is created throught **Save** method.

The compiler says this:

```
The type annotation for `update` does not match its definition.

The type annotation is saying:
 
     Main.Msg -> Main.Model -> ( Main.Model, Cmd Main.Msg )
 
 But I am inferring that the definition has this type:
 
     Main.Msg -> Main.Model -> ( Main.Model, Cmd Decoder.Msg )at line 100 col 10
```

**Main.elm**

```
    bla bla bla

    import Components.Decoder as Decoder exposing (..)

    type alias Item =
        { name : String
        , qty : Int
        }


    type alias Model =
        { name : String
        , items : List Item
        , images : Images
        }


    type Msg
        = Save
        | Input String
        | Delete Item
        | Clear
        | Sum Item Int
        | NoOp

    bla bla bla


    update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
         update msg model =
          case msg of
              Save ->
              --( add model, Cmd.none )
              ( add model, fetchCmd )

              Input name ->
                ( { model | name = name }, Cmd.none )

               Sum item number ->
                 ( sum model item number, Cmd.none )

              Delete item ->
                ( delete model item, Cmd.none )

               Clear ->
                 ( { model | name = "" }, Cmd.none )

               NoOp ->
               ( model, Cmd.none )
```

**Decoder.elm**

```
module Components.Decoder exposing (..)

import Http exposing (..)
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder, (:=))
import String
import Task exposing (Task)


type Msg
    = Fetch
    | FetchSucceed Images
    | FetchFail Http.Error


type alias Model =
    { id : Int
    , albumId : Int
    , title : String
    , url : String
    , thumbnailUrl : String
    }


type alias Images =
    List Model


url : String
url =
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos"


stringToInt : Decoder String -> Decoder Int
stringToInt d =
    Decode.customDecoder d String.toInt


decoder : Decoder Model
decoder =
    Decode.object5 Model
        ("id" := Decode.string |> stringToInt)
        ("albumId" := Decode.string |> stringToInt)
        ("title" := Decode.string)
        ("url" := Decode.string)
        ("thumbnailUrl" := Decode.string)


decoderAll : Decoder Images
decoderAll =
    Decode.list decoder


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Fetch ->
            ( model, fetchCmd )

        FetchSucceed images ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        FetchFail _ ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )


fetchTask : Task Http.Error Images
fetchTask =
    Http.get decoderAll url


fetchCmd : Cmd Msg
fetchCmd =
    Task.perform FetchFail FetchSucceed fetchTask


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend prematurely splitting your application in to separate components.

The problem you are facing is mostly caused by the fact, that `Decoder.fetchCmd` results in to `Decoder.Msg`, while you are using it inside `Main.update`

### Simple

If you are not going to reuse `Decoder` anywhere else, I would recommend to put the logic back in to `Main.elm`:

- merge `Main.update` with `Decoder.update`
- merge `Main.Msg` with `Decoder.Msg`
- `Decoder.Model` has to be a part of `Main.Model`
- handle the whole thing inside a single `update` function

### Reusable

Whatever data you want to retrieve from the server, it is supposed to be stored in the state of application, if you are planning on outputting some of it to the user.

If you really want to have a reusable component for sending `Http.get`, you will have to do something like:

```elm
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Save ->
            -- Map Decoder.msg to Main.DecoderMsg
            ( add model, Cmd.map DecoderMsg fetchCmd )

        DecoderMsg msg ->
            let
                -- Pass the message and handle the update.
                ( fetchedAlbumList, decoderCmd ) =
                    Decoder.update msg model.albumList
            in
                -- Put retrieved data in the application state
                { model | albumList = fetchedAlbumList }
```